# Windows 10 can't create shortcuts after reset

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I recently reinstalled my windows 10, and now when I try to create shortcuts in some directories (in C: for example), I get the message

> Windows can't create a shortcut here. Would you like to create it in Desktop etc...?

There are workarounds around this, but this was never a problem before the recent reinstallation. One of the workarounds is to change myself to be the owner of the folders, but I don't think it's a good idea to do to the C: drive? Also there must be a wider solution other than changing ownership to every folder I encounter this problem in separately...

My account is a local admin and was since ever, I can't recall anything different I did this time that could have caused this.

Any permenant solutions to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I have reinstalled Windows numerous times and standard installs have not created issues (or issues with shortcuts). Did you reinstall in some non-standard way?

Comment: I installed through the reset option on the recovery panel (after computer crashed).

Comment: Try fully reinstalling Windows 10 . Back up data first

Comment: I'll fo that if there would be no other option...

Comment: Yes.  Try normal shortcuts as well. Shortcuts to secured locations (lots in Windows 7 and up) tend not to work well.

Comment: Normal shortcuts are working fine, that's not the problem. I might have been unclear - the problem only appears when I try to create a shortcut in the "C:\" directory (or other system created folders), not elsewhere. 
I've researched some more and it might just have been the situation in the previous installation without me noticing or remembering it.

Answer (score 0):

It is default setting that your are not able to create shortcuts in system folder like the root of C: drive. It is the same in my case even that I am also local admin. If you try on your desktop or in your documents folder I guess there is no problem. Not sure why it worked before you reinstalled, but you might have had different folder permission on your old installation of Windows.

If you insist to create shortcuts in the root of your C: drive, you can create the shortcuts on your desktop and then copy them to the root of your C: drive afterwards, that should work.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a more permanent solution, not a one-at-a-time workaround.